# diﬀerence between counting packets and counting the total number of bytes in the packets

Tags: multithreading

I'm reading [perfbook](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html). In chapter5.2, the book give some example about statistical counters. These example can solve the network packet count problem.

> Quick Quiz 5.2: Network-packet counting problem. Suppose that you need
> to collect statistics on the number of networking packets (or total
> number of bytes) transmitted and/or received. Packets might be
> transmitted or received by any CPU on the system. Suppose further that
> this large machine is capable of handling a million packets per
> second, and that there is a system-monitoring package that reads out
> the count every ﬁve seconds. How would you implement this statistical
> counter?

There is one QuickQuiz ask about difference between counting packets and counting the total number of bytes in the packets.

I can't understand the answer. After reading it, I still don't know the difference.

The example in "To see this" paragraph, if changing number the 3 and 5 to 1, what difference does it make?

Please help me to understand it.

> **QuickQuiz5.26:** What fundamental difference is there between counting
> packets and counting the total number of bytes in the packets, given
> that the packets vary in size?
>
> **Answer:** When counting packets, the
> counter is only incremented by the value one. On the other hand, when
> counting bytes, the counter might be incremented by largish numbers.
>
> Why does this matter? Because in the increment-by-one case, the value
> returned will be exact in the sense that the counter must necessarily
> have taken on that value at some point in time, even if it is
> impossible to say precisely when that point occurred. In contrast,
> when counting bytes, two different threads might return values that are
> inconsistent with any global ordering of operations.
>
> To see this, suppose that thread 0 adds the value three to its counter,
> thread 1 adds the value ﬁve to its counter, and threads 2 and 3 sum the
> counters. If the system is “weakly ordered” or if the compiler uses
> aggressive optimizations, thread 2 might ﬁnd the sum to be three and
> thread 3 might ﬁnd the sum to be ﬁve. The only possible global orders
> of the sequence of values of the counter are 0,3,8 and 0,5,8, and
> neither order is consistent with the results obtained.
>
> If you missed > this one, you are not alone. Michael Scott used this
> question to stump Paul E. McKenney during Paul’s Ph.D. defense.

Comment: As a side note, on one machine with one firewall, you can use the `-Z` command line option of `iptables` to cleanly retrieve the counters (with `-L`) and clear them in an atomic manner (note that may have a price: it may be slow if the number of rules is really large). The problem doesn't occur in this case. Now if you have multiple machines, you bumped in the exact same issue. (although you can use a multi-machine lock too...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can be wrong but presume that idea behind that is the following: suppose there are 2 separate processes which collect their counters to be summed up for a total value. Now suppose that there are some sequences of events which occur simultaneously in both processes, for example a packet of size 10 comes to the first process and a packet of size 20 comes to the second at the same time and after some period of time a packet of size 30 comes to the first process at the same time when a packet of size 60 comes to the second process. So here is the the sequence of events:

```
           Time point#1  Time point#2
Process1:  10            30
Process2:  20            60
```

Now let's build a vector of possible total counter states after the time point #1 and #2 for a weakly ordered system, considering the previous total value was 0:

```
Time point#1
0 + 10 (process 1 wins) = 10
0 + 20 (process 2 wins) = 20
0 + 10 + 20 = 30

Time point#2
10 + 30 = 40 (process 1 wins)
10 + 60 = 70 (process 2 wins)
20 + 30 = 50 (process 1 wins)
20 + 60 = 80 (process 2 wins)
30 + 30 = 60 (process 1 wins)
30 + 60 = 90 (process 2 wins)
30 + 90 = 110
```

Now presuming that there can be some period of time between `time point#1` and `time point#2` let's assess which values reflect the real state of the system. Apparently all states after `time point#1` can be treated as valid as there was some precise moment in time when total received size was 10, 20 or 30 (we ignore the fact the the final value may not the actual one - at least it contains a value which was actual at some moment of system functioning). For the possible states after the `Time point#2` the picture is slightly different. For example the system has never been in the states 40, 70, 50 and 80 but we are under the risk to get these values after the second collection.

Now let's take a look at the situation from the number of packets perspective. Our matrix of events is:

```
           Time point#1  Time point#2
Process1:  1             1
Process2:  1             1
```

The possible total states:

```
Time point#1
0 + 1 (process 1 wins) = 1
0 + 1 (process 1 wins) = 1
0 + 1 + 1 = 2

Time point#2
1 + 1 (process 1 wins) = 2
1 + 1 (process 2 wins) = 2
2 + 1 (process 1 wins) = 3    
2 + 1 (process 2 wins) = 3
2 + 2 = 4
```

In that case all possible values (1, 2, 3, 4) reflect a state in which the system definitely was at some point in time.